# document.getElementById doesn't work in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, browser

Hi I have a JavaScript function with jQuery,
I'm facing the issue only with chrome, in all the other browsers it works fine.
the problem is that the element "change_h2" and "change_p and the src doesn't change, those are the lines that doesn't work:

```
   if ((evt.item.image.src) == imgsrc){ 
     document.getElementById("change_h2").innerHTML = "THE TEST BLA"; 
     document.getElementById("change_p").innerHTML = " Lorem22 ipsum22 Lorem 222 ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum"; 
     document.getElementById("women-eyes1").src = "images/ss2.png";
     .............
     }
```

sometimes it works for few seconds in chrome but then it stops,

I tried to clean the cache but still it doesn't work.

this is the full function:

```
$(function () {
  var carousel= $('.sky-carousel').carousel({
    enableMouseWheel: false,
    itemWidth: 135,
    itemHeight: 76,
    distance: 4,
    selectedItemDistance: 15,
    selectedItemZoomFactor: 1.4,
    unselectedItemZoomFactor:1,
    unselectedItemAlpha: 0.5,
    motionStartDistance: 150,
    topMargin: 14,
    /*gradientStartPoint: 0.35,
    gradientOverlayColor: "#f5f5f5",
    gradientOverlaySize: 190,
    reflectionDistance: 1,
    reflectionAlpha: 0.35,*/
    reflectionVisible: false, 
    /*reflectionSize: 70,*/
    selectByClick: true,
    slideSpeed:0.45,
    gradientOverlayVisible: false,  
    /* autoSlideshow: true,
    autoSlideshowDelay: 2.5, */
    autoSlideshow: true,
    autoSlideshowDelay: 2.5
  });
  var imgsrc = document.getElementById("pic1").getAttribute('src');
  var imgsrc2 = document.getElementById("pic2").getAttribute('src'); 
  carousel.on('itemSelected.sc', function (evt) {
    if ((evt.item.image.src) == imgsrc){
      document.getElementById("change_h2").innerHTML = "THE TEST BLA";   
      document.getElementById("change_p").innerHTML = " Lorem22 ipsum22 Lorem 222 ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum";
      document.getElementById("women-eyes1").src="images/ss2.png";
    } else if((evt.item.image.src) == imgsrc2) {
      document.getElementById("change_h2").innerHTML = "THE TEST BLA222";
      document.getElementById("change_p").innerHTML = " Lorem22 ipsum22 Lorem 222sum Lore";
      document.getElementById("women-eyes1").src="images/ss1.png";    
    }  
    document.getElementById("mainImage1").src= (evt.item.image.src);      
  });  
});
```

this is the HTML:

```
   <div class="carousel-inner">
 <div class="item active">
<img src="images/dragon_hunter_pic.png" alt="dragon_hunter_pic" 
id="mainImage1" >
    </div>
 </div>
  </div>
   </div>   
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-md-5 col-xs-5 col-sm-5 ">        
 <div class="women-margin">
    <img src="images/women_3.png" alt="live" id="women-eyes1" >
   </div>
        </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-md-7 col-xs-7 col-sm-7 ">

  <div class="yellow-box">
      <h2 id="change_h2">THE DRAGON HUNTER</h2>
        <br/>
        <p id="change_p"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
     adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et 
 dolor aliqua. 
  </p>
     </div>
  </div>

 </div>
   </div>


  <li> <a href="#home"><img src="images/dragon_hunter_pic.png" id="pic1" 
     alt=""  /></a></li>
        <li> <a href="#home"><img src="images/betest.png" id="pic2" 
      alt="" /></a> </li>
```

the debugger doesn't show any bug.

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery and native methods? Why not just use jQuery for everything?

Comment: I am convinced that the .getElementById() method works in Chrome the same way as in other browsers.

Comment: Any error in the console ?

Comment: no.. there is no errors

Comment: Can you add the HTML that you use?

Comment: If you debug the code, is it stepping into the code you think is not working? It could be a problem with the conditional logic rather than the getElementById...

Comment: @ggarciasoft added HTML

Comment: These statements `var imgsrc = document.getElementById("pic1").getAttribute('src');` `var imgsrc2 = document.getElementById("pic2").getAttribute('src');` does not work, maybe this causes you the problem.

Comment: I don't see neither "pic1" nor "pic2" in the markup.

Comment: @WaldemarIce  What do you mean.?

Comment: @ggarciasoft Forgot to add it, added it

Comment: @WaldemarIc but in all the other browser its works fine

Comment: @rireij Try making your question into a Snippet, `document.getElementById` works in Chrome, just like all other browsers, there is something else going on here, with a Snippet you will likely get more help.

Comment: @rireij And Chrome is really showing no errors in console?

Comment: no, it doesnt show any error

Comment: So, open the developer tool, add breakpoint on line ` var imgsrc = document.get...` and with F11, watch variable values step by step.

Comment: still didn't find anything. I don't understand why the function somtimes works in chrome and after refresh it stops working

Comment: I found the solution, added:
     $(window).on('load', function() {    to the begging of the fuction.